# Which ngen to use for x86 app on x64 system?

Tags: c#, .net, ngen

I decided to ask this question because did not find clear answer. My WPF program is x86 (.Net 4.5.2). I use Inno Setup to install and create ngen image. Should I use Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe when installing on 64bit system and Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe when installing on 32bit system or because the program is x86 I should allways use Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe?

Comment: you need to create the native image on the machine you are targeting i.e the same processor as the target machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to just try yourself by running ngen.exe from the command line.  That mixing can't work is crystal clear, it is *very* chatty about it.  I edited the output to the core message:

> 1>Ngen failed to generate native code for image
>   C:\projects2\ConsoleApplication491\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication491.exe because of the following error:
>   The image  file is not compatible with the version of Ngen you're
>   running.  **Use 32bit Ngen  for 32bit assemblies, and 64bit Ngen for
>   64bit assemblies**. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131F07)

Produced with a little test project that targets x86 and running the 64-bit version of ngen.exe.

Comment: NGEN is a little bit less clear when your assembly targets AnyCPU. In that case, it will successfully generate images for 32 bit or 64 bit, depending on the NGEN version you run. However, when on a 64 bit Windows system (which is most nowadays), the ngen'ed images will only be chosen by Fusion when you specifically create images for 64 bit. Note that the default NGEN version when starting the VS2017 command prompt is the 32 bit version, this can therefore be rather confusing.

Answer (score 1):

x86 (32-bit applications) can run on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows machines.

x64 can run on 64-bit Windows machines only.

Therefore, if you target your application as an x86 application while compiling in Visual Studio, you should use 32-bit `ngen` on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows machines.